# Who played "camel toe annie" on Conan's show?

Tags: comedy

Who played "camel toe annie" on Late Night with Conan O'Brien?
Some guys on [this forum](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-272624.html) think its Amy Poehler but she barely looks any thing like her in this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNwuk4SwHT8)

Answer (score 3):

This just came up on a recent episode of the Conan O’Brien Needs A Friend podcast. Apparently the actress was Cecelia Pleva, who was also a casting director for the show: